# How to split a string and create a json object in java?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to split a string and create a json object with it. But somehow I can't create the json object. Json object "objectBuilder" doesn't get the value. Please help.

I have book number like: "bookNo":"120, 130, 140". Here bookNo could be change and comes with 2 values or more. These book no., I'm getting from the database. And I can't change the Json API. It should be javax.json api.

```
    for(BookTerm dataTable:list){
        URL url1 = new URL("http://books.google.com/type/");
        JsonObjectBuilder objectBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        String uriAdd = dataTable.getBookNo().toString();
        String[] uriLink = uriAdd.split(", ");
        int i = 0;
        String uriLink1 = null;
           if(uriLink != null){
               while (i< uriLink.length){
                   uriLink1 = uriLink[i];
                   URL url2 = new URL(url1.getProtocol(), url1.getHost(), url1.getPort(), url1.getPath() + uriLink1, null);
                   uriAdd1 = url2.toString();
                   i++;
                   objectBuilder.add("bookNumber", uriLink1)
                      .add("uri", uriAdd1).build();
               }
           }
    }
```

Output will be:

```
    {
         "bookNumber":"120",
         "uri":"http://books.google.com/type/120"
    },
    {
         "bookNumber":"130",
         "uri":"http://books.google.com/type/130"
    }
```

and so on.

Comment: `But somehow I can't create the json object` Why not?

Comment: I don't know what I'm missing here. If I print the value, it prints out but can't create the Json object with it.

Comment: do you get any exception in return ?

Comment: I'm getting this if I print json object: org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl@18339d4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used JsonObjectBuilder before but it looks like you are never saving a reference to the JsonObject that the builder created on your line with .build(). Also, you are constantly adding the same key to the builder's object, simply overwriting it each time. You want to create an ArrayBuilder and have multiple ObjectBuilders inside of it like this:

```
JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory();
JsonObject value = factory.createArrayBuilder();

while(haveObjects) {
   value.add(Json.createObjectBuilder().add("bookNumber", uriLink1).add("uri", uriAdd1).build());
}
// writer will be constructed with some sort of output, and this will write the JSON value to it.
JsonWriter writer = Json.createWriter();
writer.write(value);
```

Comment: you can't add object with value. There has no option for it.

Comment: According to the docs there is... https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArrayBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO class with attributes `bookNumber` and `uri` and override toString method just like :

```
public class Book{
private String bookNumber;
private String uri;

//define a constructor with parameters
public Book(String bookNumber, String uri){
this.bookNumber = bookNumber;
this.uri=uri;
}


// define getters setters
// public String getBooknumber(..) etc.


@Override
    public String toString(){
        return "obj{bookNumber:" + "\"" + this.bookNumber + "\"" +", uri:"+ "\"" +  this.uri }" ;
    }
}
```

In your class make an instance of Book class and create a JSONObject:

```
Book book = new Book("123214213", "http://www.sth.com");
JSONObject jsobject = new JSONObject(book.toString());

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(jsobject);

//.....
```